# When designing a medieval style Tabletop RPG, which style has proven more popular: historically accurate social views, or modern views?

Tags: game-design, social, rpg-theory

In the wake of recent events, I've become honestly curious as to what sales figures and/or other social media metrics might reveal about our shifting views regarding what is or is not popular and acceptable in tabletop role playing games.

Medieval beliefs and views (generically speaking) tended towards black and white, strongly religious (not always in a positive way), and varying degrees of xenophobia or tolerance towards different cultures and practices.

Modern social views eschew many of the views and beliefs common during those historical times.

Thus when designing a game based on a historical (medieval) period which might include such sensitive historically accurate topics such as plague, racism, social and religious discrimination, slavery, and other challenging subject matters, what metrics exists that reveal which is preferred today?

Thus when designing a medieval style Tabletop RPG, which style has proven more popular by the numbers: historically accurate social views, or historically inaccurate but more acceptable modern social views?

Comment: I will point out that race as a concept resembling our modern notions did not exist until after the medieval period.  So in reality rather than being more racist, "racism" did not really exist.  This doesn't mean they were tolerant, but that issues other than race (such as **social class**, religion, language, country of origin etc.) were far more important.  The point being If you are designing an RPG to be socially accurate make sure you actually research medieval social values rather than just assume history is some linear progression from less to more woke.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. Beyond the fact that we have absolutely zero hard sales data for anything in the industry, the definitions of what counts as “historically accurate” (or aiming to be, it claiming to be) vs. what counts as “modern” (or aiming to be, or claiming to be) is assumed to be some clear, binary choice when in reality it’s not at all clear what should count as each, and reality is that it would be a spectrum and a lot of products arguably aren’t even on it.

Comment: For the obvious example (and in terms of popularity, the only one that matters anyway), we have D&D, where the most recent _Player’s Handbook_ embraces decidedly modern social views (though I hesitate to say there has never and nowhere been similar views elsewhere and elsewhen). Its only conceivable competition in popularity are older editions of D&D—and are those in a “historically accurate” style? They certainly aren’t historically accurate—for the most part, they really just capture the social mores of their own era, just as in modern D&D, with some ahistorical myth and fantasy thrown in.

Comment: And really, I highly doubt there has ever been an RPG that really *is* historically accurate—certainly, any time we see an RPG claiming to be, it almost certainly isn’t, and there is a distressingly high probability that what it actually is, is hideously racist and sexist in ways that _don’t_ reflect historical reality. Cf. _FATAL_, for the most extreme example.

Comment: Have you considered, that it's not so much the game (rules), it's the game world (campaign setting) which determines this, mostly?

Comment: I feel like you'd need to better define "historically accurate social views" to answer this question, such as defining a time and place and referencing sources. Even so, the answer might still reduce down to the fact that the most popular and most influential medieval fantasy RPG, Dungeons & Dragons, is frequently not historically accurate, either as written or as played.

Answer (score 6):

### “Modern,” by default, just because that describes at least some of D&D

D&D is not, and never has been, historically accurate, nor has it ever intended to be, or been claimed to be.

Sometimes—e.g. currently—D&D has embraced more progressive social causes of the era of publication, and other times—e.g. Gygax’s original writing—it has not particularly. But that isn’t the same as saying that it embraced a “historically-accurate style” whatever that means—it just means that it made no overt attempt to embrace contemporary progressive views. Gygax was trying to capture the feel of certain fantasy and Romance narratives, not history. He mostly just captured his own social views, which was fine from the perspective of being compatible with his goals and his claims. After all, Gygax’s conception of the game includes heavily authoritarian DMing styles, where the world *should* reflect whatever the DM wants. As the author of the game, that just makes him kind of the “ultimate DM” in a sense.

All of which is to say, simply, that “modern” sensibilities must win this debate by default—at least some editions of D&D, i.e. the current one, have explicitly embraced modern mores. No edition of D&D has been particularly historically-minded with respect to social mores.

So that means “modern” has at least some D&D in its column, and “historically accurate style” does not. And in terms of sales, “at least some of D&D” absolutely swamps literally the entirety of the non-D&D RPG industry.

Which is good, because if we didn’t have a default answer like this, we could not have an answer.